# What happens when Future is given then Thread is cancelled or killed?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I still new to future and multi-threading. I have a flow in mind that goes like this:

callable A is a publisher to a Queue C and Thread B is a consumer to the Queue C. The Queue C will expect Futures from A so that B can continue the computation. Executor of A will pass the future into the queue C and Thread B will be using **future.get()** and wait for the result before going further.

I am wondering if callable A fails and B is still listening to the future, what will happen ? and if B threads is taking a longer time to finish, and A returns the value earlier while still in the queue C, what would happen ?

Comment: Please can you show us some code? It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadocs?  `Future.get()` throws a `CancellationException` if the thread is cancelled and an `ExecutionException` if the thread fails with an exception.

Comment: So if Callable A is interrupted or killed abruptly , Future.get() will return ExecutionException ? What happens when it returns earlier while still queuing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc of `Future.get()` tells:

> Waits **if necessary** for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

Assume the following sequence:

- A puts a Future object X to the queue C
- A finishes its computation of X
- B retrieves X from queue C

When B now calls `X.get()` the computation result is returned without blocking (in case X is implemented a specified in javadoc).